# Using relational algebra, find those drinkers who can find all the beers he likes in a bar that he frequents

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

```
Drinker (drinker, age, address)
Like(drinker, beer)
Beer (beer, manufacturer)
Bar (bar, owner, address)
Frequent(drinker, bar)
Sell (bar, beer, price)
```

Find those drinkers who can find all the beers he likes in a bar that he frequents.

am not sure about my answer and would like some verification on whether I am on the right track:

```
R1:=πdrinker,bar,beer(LIKE⨝FREQUENT) 
R2:=πdrinker,bar,beer(FREQUENT⨝SELL)
R3:=πdrinker,bar(R1-R2)
Solution:= FREQUENT - R3
```

R1 attempts to get all set of drinker,beer liked, bar visited

R2 attempts to get all set of beer from all bars a drinker frequent

R3 get all drinker and bar composition that do not satisfy all beer liked by drinking

Finally, subtracting these set(R3) from the entire set

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> R1:=πdrinker,bar,beer(LIKE⨝FREQUENT)
> ```

This is rows where `Like(drinker, beer) AND Frequent(drinker, bar)`. Did you need to project? Is it reasonable to project anyway?

> ```
> R2:=πdrinker,bar,beer(FREQUENT⨝SELL)
> ```

This is rows where `FOR SOME price, Frequent(drinker, bar) AND Sell(bar, beer, price)`. Did you need to project? Is it reasonable to project anyway?

> ```
> R3:=πdrinker,bar(R1-R2)
> ```

This is rows where

```
FOR SOME beer,
        Like(drinker, beer) AND Frequent(drinker, bar)
    AND NOT FOR SOME price, Frequent(drinker, bar) AND Sell(bar, beer, price)
```

> ```
> Solution:= FREQUENT - R3
> ```

This is rows where

```
    Frequent(drinker, bar)
AND NOT FOR SOME beer,
            Like(drinker, beer) AND Frequent(drinker, bar)  
        AND NOT FOR SOME price, Frequent(drinker, bar) AND Sell(bar, beer, price)
```

How can I justify my claims?

This is

```
    Frequent(drinker, bar)
AND FOR ALL beer,
            NOT (Like(drinker, beer) AND Frequent(drinker, bar))
        OR FOR SOME price, Frequent(drinker, bar) AND Sell(bar, beer, price)
```

Ie

```
    Frequent(drinker, bar)
AND FOR ALL beer,
            Like(drinker, beer) AND Frequent(drinker, bar)
        IMPLIES FOR SOME price, Frequent(drinker, bar) AND Sell(bar, beer, price)
```

Ie

```
    Frequent(drinker, bar)
AND FOR ALL beer,
        Like(drinker, beer) IMPLIES FOR SOME price, Sell(bar, beer, price)
```

Why?

This is rows where *drinker* frequents *bar* and for all beer, if the-drinker likes the-beer then the-bar sells the-beer at some-price. Is this correct?

If `R` & `S` hold rows where `R(...)` & `S(...)` respectively then what does the relation holding rows where `R(...) OR S(...)` look like? How could you calculate it? Why is that a problem? What if `R` & `S` have the same attributes in `...`? What about `IMPLIES`?

What are some heuristics we can use to start from something simple like the final informal expression and try to get those (`Like`s with those) `drinker`s & `bar`s down into the `FOR ALL` and `IMPLIES`? Ie to start with the simple version and work up generating my rewritings?

A mechanical way to do that, ie that always works, uses *prenex normal form* as Codd used in proving *Codd's theorem* which says that (a form of) relational algebra could express anything that (a form of) relational calculus could.